# ATS for HTTP request based on IP not work

Tags: ios, http, https, ip, app-transport-security

[NSAppTransportSecurity section - [Availability of ATS for Remote and Local Connections]‌](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW59) said, ATS applies only to connections made to public host names. The system does not provide ATS protection to connections made to:
- Internet protocol(IP) address;
- Unqualified host names;
- Local hosts employing the .local top-level domain(TLD).
Now I am working on the ATS+HTTPS issue to let my SDK suit the requirement mentioned in WWDC 2016. Server API using domains will change to use HTTPS in no doubt.

But now that server API using IP address (not domain) works well under ATS in iOS 10+ but not in iOS 9. It seems that the system does not provide ATS protection to connections to IP address in iOS 10 system. Who can explain this or any doc  to refer?
So does that means  keep using server API using IP address will work well in the future? Will it triger the addtional App Store Review?

Comment: I am confused by your question.  Are you asking how to *disable* ATS on connections made to IP addresses as opposed to domains?  ATS *exceptions* can only be made based on domains at this point, meaning you can choose to be less secure on some connections to domain names.   There are solutions to add exceptions to IP addresses, but not ones that I would use in an app in the App Store.  Do you not own the API servers for which you only have IP addresses?  Do those IP addresses really not have domain names associated with them?

Comment: What I mean is that,  ATS is not enabled to HTTP request using IP address in iOS 10+. Even with ATS enabled, HTTP connection using IP address works well.

Comment: What I mean is that,  ATS is not enabled to HTTP request using IP address in iOS 10+. Even with ATS enabled, HTTP connection using IP address works well in iOS 10, but not in iOS 9.   We will change the server API to suit the HTTPS requirement. I just want to is there any official doc to explain it?